Why is $k[x,y]/(x,y)^2$ not an injective module over itself?
Consider $R=k[x,y]/(x^2,xy,y^2)$ where $k$ is a field.

Why is it not a self-injective ring?

I was trying to use Baer's criterion. But I was unable to find an ideal for which there is a non-extendable map for the inclusion $I \subset R$.
